# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called when using with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, alamofire

I made a function that calls list of user api
and I put it in `viewDidLoad` so that I can get the list in `TableViewCell` as soon as screen get loaded.

But the problem is after calling of `numberOfRowsInSection`, Alalmofire.rquest gets called automatically and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not getting called hence `TableView` is empty.

```
 func userList(){

    let header = [

         "some header":"SomeHeaderValue"
    ]

    var request = BaseUrl + "userList"

    let parameters = ["":""]

    var encodingFormat: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding()
    if request == "" {
        encodingFormat = JSONEncoding()
    }

    Alamofire.request(request, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: encodingFormat, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)

                self.userArray = data as! [AnyHashable]

            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to reload the `tableView` after the response has been received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Network calls are asynchronous and take time. You need to reload the `tableView` after receiving the data.

```
 Alamofire.request(request, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: encodingFormat, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)

                self.userArray = data as! [AnyHashable]
                print(self.groupArray)
                print(self.groupArray.count)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error)
            break
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let data = response.result.value{
                print(response.result.value)

                self.userArray = data as! [AnyHashable]
                print(self.groupArray)
                print(self.groupArray.count)

                self.tableview.reloadData()

 }
 break
```