# Added data to a dictionary inside of a closure, dictionary empty

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift4

I am having a problem with a dictionary in a closure.  I created a dictionary variable:

```
var dates = [String:String]()
```

I have then populated the dictionary with the following code:

```
// Function to Retrieve Dates from iCloud
@objc func dotDates() {

    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Events", predicate: predicate)

    database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) {
        (records, error) in

        if error == nil {

            for record in records! {

                self.jobHold = record["jobName"]!
                self.dateHold = record["jobDateTime"]!

                // Date Conversion to CVDate
                let conversion = Convert()
                self.dateHold = conversion.convertStringToDate(date: self.dateHold)

                // Store Dates in a Dictionary
                self.dates[self.dateHold] = self.jobHold

            }

        } else {

            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
        }
    }

    print("**********", self.dates, "**********")
}
```

The debug area shows the data is there:

```
********** ["8 October, 2018": "Anchor Lodge Rehab",
"7 October, 2018": "Anchor Lodge Office", "15 October,
2018": "Jarm", "12 October, 2018": "North Shore Endo",
"17 October, 2018": "Kidsmile Fresh"] **********
```

My problem is when I try to access the dictionary elsewhere in the code, the dictionary is empty.

```
// Display dots for date events
func dotMarker(shouldShowOnDayView dayView: DayView) -> Bool{

    print("**********", dates, "**********")

    // Look up date in dictionary
    if(dates[dayView.date.commonDescription] != nil){
        return true // date is in the array so draw a dot
    }
    return false
}
```

Debug area shows:

```
********** [:] **********
********** [:] **********
********** [:] **********
```

I'm not sure why it is empty?  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Asynchronous execution, your dictionary has not been created yet by the time you are printing it. Check with breakpoints when the print is called and when the dictionary is set.

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/51871992/7734643 In your case, instead of reloading, it's just printing.